# Group a list of tuples on two values, and return a list of all the third value

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list of tuples and each tuple contains three values.  I want to 'roll them up' or group them so that for all tuples where the first two values are the same it will return a list of lists where each component list contains: 1: the first value, 2: the second value, 3: a list of all the 3rd values that match the first two.

Because I am writing the whole script here I have some flexibility on data types so if I am approaching it in a completely wrong manner please let me know.  I did wonder if there was an easier way to accomplish it using Pandas.

I am wondering if using `itertools.groupby()` it may be possible to accomplish this.  I think it would probably need to be combined with `operator.itemgetter()` to access the correct parts of the various tuples.

```py
import itertools
import operator

list = [(1, 1, 4), (1, 1, 9), (1, 1, 14), (2, 1, 12), (2, 1, 99), (2, 6, 14), (2, 6, 19)]

list=sorted(list)

def sorter(list):
     grouper = itertools.groupby(list, operator.itemgetter(0))
     for key, subiter in grouper:
          l = []
          grouper2 = itertools.groupby(subiter, operator.itemgetter(0))
          for key, subiter in grouper2: 
               l.append(subiter)
               yield key, l
```

This code represents the general direction I was thinking, but it will not yield the desired output.  The desired output for this would be:

```
[[1, 1, [4, 9, 14]], [2, 1, [12, 99]], [2, 6, [14, 19]]]
```

Again I have significant flexibility in terms of the datatypes here so if I am approaching this wrong I am willing to try something completely different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need to use two nested `groupby` grouping by a single field. Instead use `itemgetter` with two parameters or a `lambda` to group by both the first two values at once, then a list comprehension to get the final elements.

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> lst = [(1, 1, 4), (1, 1, 9), (1, 1, 14), (2, 1, 12), (2, 1, 99), (2, 6, 14), (2, 6, 19)]
>>> [(*k, [x[2] for x in g]) for k, g in groupby(lst, key=itemgetter(0, 1))]
[(1, 1, [4, 9, 14]), (2, 1, [12, 99]), (2, 6, [14, 19])]
```

If, for whatever reason, you *want* to use two separate `groupby`, you can use this:

```
>>> [(k1, k2, [x[2] for x in g2]) for k1, g1 in groupby(lst, key=itemgetter(0))
...                               for k2, g2 in groupby(g1,  key=itemgetter(1))]
[(1, 1, [4, 9, 14]), (2, 1, [12, 99]), (2, 6, [14, 19])]
```

Of course, this also works as a regular (nested) loop, more in line with your original code:

```
def sorter(lst):
     for k1, g1 in groupby(lst, key=itemgetter(0)):
         for k2, g2 in groupby(g1, key=itemgetter(1)):
             yield (k1, k2, [x[2] for x in g2])
```

Or with the single `groupby`, returning a generator object:

```
def sorter(lst):
    return ((*k, [x[2] for x in g]) for k, g in groupby(lst, key=itemgetter(0, 1)))
```

As always, this assumes that `lst` is already `sorted` by the same `key`. If it is not, sort it first.

Comment: Note that if the input is not already sorted, instead of sorting it first, which would make the solution take an average time complexity of *O(n log n)*, it would be more efficient to switch to one of the dict-based solutions in the other answers to keep the cost of time at a linear complexity.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative approach is to use a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) like so

```
from collections import defaultdict
x = [(1, 1, 4), (1, 1, 9), (1, 1, 14), (2, 1, 12), (2, 1, 99), (2, 6, 14), (2, 6, 19)]
d = defaultdict(list)
for i in x:
    d[i[:2]].append(i[2])
out = [[*i, j] for i, j in d.items()]
print(out)
```

prints

```
[[1, 1, [4, 9, 14]], [2, 1, [12, 99]], [2, 6, [14, 19]]]
```

Comment: Might want to point out that this only works if the elements in the list are tuples (which they are in this case), otherwise (for lists) `d[i[:2]]`  will not work.

Comment: @tobias_k yes good point. As the question is about a list of tuples I think it's ok, but thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a dict that maps the keys to the values by appending the values to a sub-list while iterating through the input list, and then use a list comprehension to iterate through the dict items to output the desired sub-lists with the keys unpacked:

```
lst = [(1, 1, 4), (1, 1, 9), (1, 1, 14), (2, 1, 12), (2, 1, 99), (2, 6, 14), (2, 6, 19)]
mapping = {}
for *keys, value in lst:
    mapping.setdefault(tuple(keys), []).append(value)
print([[*keys, value] for keys, value in mapping.items()])
```

This outputs:

```
[[1, 1, [4, 9, 14]], [2, 1, [12, 99]], [2, 6, [14, 19]]]
```

Comment: Your solution has the same result as mine but is more concise. Can you explain how the splat operator works in `for *keys, value in lst:`? How does it know to get only the first two elements of the tuple?

Comment: The item with the unpacking operator gets the rest of the slice after the positions of the other items are resolved. You can refer to [PEP-3132](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/) for a good explanation of how it works.

Comment: Nice, but only works if the key are always the first n-1 elements.

Comment: @tobias_k Yes, which should be fine per the OP's description of the specs of the input.

Answer (score 1):

tobias_k beat me to it. Using groupby assumes that the tuples belonging to the same groups are next to each other.

```
from itertools import groupby


tuples = [
    (1, 1, 4),
    (1, 1, 9),
    (1, 1, 14),
    (2, 1, 12),
    (2, 1, 99),
    (2, 6, 14),
    (2, 6, 19)
]

lists = [[*key, list(t[2] for t in group)] for key, group in groupby(tuples, key=lambda t: t[:2])]
print(lists)
```

Answer (score 1):

The pandas version can be done like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(l, columns=['a', 'b', 'c']) # create dataframe
df = df.groupby(['a', 'b'])['c'].apply(list).to_frame().reset_index() #groubpy and create the list
df.values.tolist() # unlist row to list of lists

[[1, 1, [4, 9, 14]], [2, 1, [12, 99]], [2, 6, [14, 19]]]
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use `set` to create a unique set of keys (of tuples), then just go through the list and append the 3rd value to the key in the dictionary. If you want to convert it to a list of lists later, you could.

```py
list = [(1, 1, 4), (1, 1, 9), (1, 1, 14), (2, 1, 12), (2, 1, 99), (2, 6, 14), (2, 6, 19)]

setoftuples = set((item[0],item[1]) for item in list)

dictoftuples = {n: [] for n in setoftuples}

for tup in list:
    dictoftuples[(tup[0],tup[1])].append(tup[2])

print(dictoftuples)
```